# winamp: Change playlist behaviour

Tags: winamp

Is there a way I can change the behavior of single click in winamp's playlist? E.g. I want song to be started after a clicking on it. How do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [Single Click 'n' Play](https://winampplugins.co.uk/singleclick.html) plugin for Winamp.

[image: Screenshot]