# winamp: Scrolling playlist on mouse move over playlist

Tags: winamp

I have a touchscreen (Asus EEE top). In winamp when I move my fingers over play list it pans songs. I wonder if there is a way to change the behavior of this to scroling.. Would be really helpful.

I am already using click and play plugin as suggested here ([winamp: Change playlist behaviour](https://superuser.com/questions/265321/winamp-change-playlist-behaviour))... So maybe there is something similar?